# PowerShell trouble with base64 encoding

Tags: powershell

I need to turn an array of comma-seperated values (a .csv) into a bit of JSON that looks like this:

```
"traits": {
  "file": {
    "content": "R0lGODlhABAQAIAAAAAAAP///yH7BAEAAAAALAAAAAAEAABAAAIBRAA5",
    "file_name": "test.png"
  }
}
```

I am using the following:

```
$traits = New-Object PSObject
$file = New-Object PSObject
$file | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name file_name -Value "file.csv"
$file | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name content -Value $([Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes(($domain.GPOs | ConvertTo-Csv))))
$traits | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name group-policies -Value $file
```

It seems that the content of "content" is incorrectly encoded. To troubleshoot, I copied the content to www.freeformatter.com/base64-encoder.html and found that they don't match.

What am I missing?

Edit: Here is the content of the .csv. This is what I pasted into https://www.freeformatter.com/base64-encoder.html#ad-output:

```
#TYPE Selected.System.Xml.XmlElement
"Name","GUID","Linked To","Computer Settings","User Settings"
"Autodiscover - Shared Namespace","249b1923-523a-40b6-9180-cc2727414b9b","@{OU Name=servers; OU Path=domain.local/location/servers; Enabled=true; Enforced=false}","@{Enabled=true; Settings=}","@{Enabled=true; Settings=}"
```

Powershell outputs this:

```
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
```

The website spits out:

```
I1RZUEUgU2VsZWN0ZWQuU3lzdGVtLlhtbC5YbWxFbGVtZW50DQoiTmFtZSIsIkdVSUQiLCJMaW5rZWQgVG8iLCJDb21wdXRlciBTZXR0aW5ncyIsIlVzZXIgU2V0dGluZ3MiDQoiQXV0b2Rpc2NvdmVyIC0gU2hhcmVkIE5hbWVzcGFjZSIsIjI0OWIxOTIzLTUyM2EtNDBiNi05MTgwLWNjMjcyNzQxNGI5YiIsIkB7T1UgTmFtZT1zZXJ2ZXJzOyBPVSBQYXRoPWRvbWFpbi5sb2NhbC9sb2NhdGlvbi9zZXJ2ZXJzOyBFbmFibGVkPXRydWU7IEVuZm9yY2VkPWZhbHNlfSIsIkB7RW5hYmxlZD10cnVlOyBTZXR0aW5ncz19IiwiQHtFbmFibGVkPXRydWU7IFNldHRpbmdzPX0i
```

Comment: Can you show some sample source data and how you are reading it. I don't even see where you try to convert it to JSON

Comment: I'm trying to get to JSON like that, but the encoding is wrong.

Comment: `[System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes(...)` -> `[System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(...)`. Your script uses a different encoding.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I did try with `[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes(...)` and get the same result as with ASCII but they only match up to the 48th position, presumably line endings don't match.

Comment: @LotPings You get a matching result because UTF-8 was designed for backwards compatibility with ASCII. And yes, trailing line breaks probably account for differences at the end of the encoded strings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three (potential) problems:

- **Character encoding**:

  - [www.freeformatter.com](https://www.freeformatter.com/base64-encoder.html#ad-output) bases the Base64 encoding on the input string's *UTF-8* encoding.
  - Your PowerShell code uses UTF-16LE ("`Unicode`") encoding as the basis; use `[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes()` instead, if you want UTF-8.
- **Style of newlines** (line endings)

  - Newlines in text pasted at [www.freeformatter.com](https://www.freeformatter.com/base64-encoder.html#ad-output) are quietly converted to Windows-style CRLF newlines, whereas your input *may* have Unix-style LF-only newlines.
- **Newlines getting lost**:

  - You're passing the output from `ConvertTo-Csv`, which is an *array* of strings to `[System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes()`, which expects a *single* string. In the process PowerShell *stringifies* the array, which means that its elements are joined with a *space* as the separator, so the original newlines are replaced with spaces, resulting in different encoded output.
  - Therefore, instead of `($domain.GPOs | ConvertTo-Csv)`, use `($domain.GPOs | ConvertTo-Csv) -join [Environment]::NewLine` (which uses the platform-appropriate newline sequence; alternatively, use `` "`n" `` or `` "`r`n" `` explicitly; also, you may want to append a *trailing* newline).